# Embed LibVLC into my android app is not playing video, only audio is being played

Tags: android, video, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

After a 3 days journey, I finally got libvlc-3.0.0-2.1.0.aar compiled for embedding VLC player into my Android (tv) app.

After adapting the [LibVLC Android Sample](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample/overview) into my project I finally run the app.

Problem: Only audio is being played. Video never appears (the surface view stays black). I've tested with different videos and the image never appears.

Any idea of why the video is not being played? Here is an example of a video that I'm trying to play (http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4)

My setup: 
I've burned an [android tv image](http://geektillithertz.com/wordpress/index.php/2016/06/02/android-tv-for-raspberry-pi-3/) into my RPI3 and the app is running there.

UPDATE: I've tried the VLC original app (from apk) and it's happening the same.

Here's the code of my Activity:

```
public class MyVideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements IVLCVout.Callback{

    public final static String TAG = "VideoActivity";

    // display surface
    private SurfaceView mSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    // media player
    private LibVLC libvlc;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;
    private final static int VideoSizeChanged = -1;

    private String mFilePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_video_player);

        mSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        holder = mSurface.getHolder();
        //mFilePath = new String("http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8");
        //http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4
        //http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4
        mFilePath = new String("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/3gp/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_30mb.3gp");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        createPlayer(mFilePath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releasePlayer();
    }

    /*************
     * Surface
     *************/
    private void setSize(int width, int height) {
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mVideoWidth * mVideoHeight <= 1)
            return;

        if(holder == null || mSurface == null)
            return;

        // get screen size
        int w = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
        int h = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();

        // getWindow().getDecorView() doesn't always take orientation into
        // account, we have to correct the values
        boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        if (w > h && isPortrait || w < h && !isPortrait) {
            int i = w;
            w = h;
            h = i;
        }

        float videoAR = (float) mVideoWidth / (float) mVideoHeight;
        float screenAR = (float) w / (float) h;

        if (screenAR < videoAR)
            h = (int) (w / videoAR);
        else
            w = (int) (h * videoAR);

        // force surface buffer size
        holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);

        // set display size
        LayoutParams lp = mSurface.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = w;
        lp.height = h;
        mSurface.setLayoutParams(lp);
        mSurface.invalidate();
    }

    /*************
     * Player
     *************/

    private void createPlayer(String media) {
        releasePlayer();
        try {
            if (media.length() > 0) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, media, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,
                        0);
                toast.show();
            }

            // Create LibVLC
            // TODO: make this more robust, and sync with audio demo
            ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
            //options.add("--subsdec-encoding <encoding>");
            options.add("--aout=opensles");
            options.add("--audio-time-stretch"); // time stretching
            //options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
            libvlc = new LibVLC(this, options);
            holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

            // Create media player
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc);
            mMediaPlayer.setEventListener(mPlayerListener);

            // Set up video output
            final IVLCVout vout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
            vout.setVideoView(mSurface);
            //vout.setSubtitlesView(mSurfaceSubtitles);
            vout.addCallback(this);
            vout.attachViews();

            Media m = new Media(libvlc, (Uri.parse(media)) );
            mMediaPlayer.setMedia(m);
            mMediaPlayer.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error creating player!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    // TODO: handle this cleaner
    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (libvlc == null)
            return;

        Log.d(TAG, "Releasing Player");
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        final IVLCVout vout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
        vout.removeCallback(this);
        vout.detachViews();
        holder = null;
        libvlc.release();
        libvlc = null;

        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
    }

    public void finishActivity() {
        finish();
    }
    /*************
     * Events
     *************/

    private MediaPlayer.EventListener mPlayerListener = new MyPlayerListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onNewLayout(IVLCVout vout, int width, int height, int visibleWidth, int visibleHeight, int sarNum, int sarDen) {
        if (width * height == 0)
            return;

        // store video size
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        setSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        Log.d(TAG, "OnNewLayout " + mVideoWidth + "x" + mVideoHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfacesCreated(IVLCVout vout) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSurfacesCreated " + vout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfacesDestroyed(IVLCVout vout) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSurfacesDestroyed " + vout);
    }


    private static class MyPlayerListener implements MediaPlayer.EventListener {
        private WeakReference<MyVideoPlayerActivity> mOwner;

        public MyPlayerListener(MyVideoPlayerActivity owner) {
            mOwner = new WeakReference<MyVideoPlayerActivity>(owner);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer.Event event) {
            MyVideoPlayerActivity player = mOwner.get();

            switch(event.type) {
                case org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached:
                    Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayerEndReached");
                    player.releasePlayer();
                    break;
                case org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer.Event.Playing:
                    Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer Playing");
                case org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer.Event.Paused:
                    Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer Paused");
                case org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer.Event.Stopped:
                    Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer Stopped");
                    //player.releasePlayer();
                    //player.finishActivity();
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the code of the resource/layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MyVideoPlayerActivity" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's a copy past of the adb log:
Full log in this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx62BNfVLJZDdTl1VjlKS1oxWXc/view?usp=sharing)

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
D/VLC: [a2fb0db8/656c706d] core libvlc: VLC media player - 3.0.0-git Vetinari
D/VLC: [a2fb0db8/79746976] core libvlc: Copyright © 1996-2016 the VideoLAN team
D/VLC: [a2fb0db8/160013] core libvlc: revision 2.2.0-git-8758-gb0f06e8
D/VLC: [a2fb0db8/a0497a18] core libvlc: configured with ../configure  '--host=arm-linux-androideabi' '--build=x86_64-unknown-linux' '--with-contrib=/home/edup/sources/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi' '--enable-neon' '--disable-nls' '--enable-live555' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-avformat' '--enable-swscale' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-opus' '--enable-opensles' '--enable-mkv' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--disable-vlc' '--disable-shared' '--disable-update-check' '--disable-vlm' '--disable-dbus' '--enable-lua' '--disable-vcd' '--disable-v4l2' '--disable-gnomevfs' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-dvdnav' '--disable-bluray' '--disable-linsys' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-libva' '--disable-dv1394' '--enable-mod' '--disable-sid' '--disable-gme' '--disable-tremor' '--disable-mad' '--enable-mpg123' '--disable-dca' '--disable-sdl-image' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-fluidsynth' '--enable-fluidlite' '--disable-jack' '--disable-pulse' '--disable-alsa' '--disable-samplerate' '--disable-sdl' '--disable-xcb' 
D/VLC: [a2fb0db8/a2f78580] core libvlc: plug-ins loaded: 286 modules
D/VLC: [a2f3a2c8/a2f78580] core logger: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
D/VLC: [a2f3a2c8/120000] core logger: using logger module "android_logger"
D/VLC: [a2fb0db8/af3] core libvlc: translation test: code is "C"
D/VLC: [a2f3a328/af3] core keystore: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 3 candidates
D/VLC: [a2f3a328/af3] core keystore: using keystore module "memory"
D/VLC: [a2fb0db8/af3] core libvlc: CPU has capabilities ARM_NEON FPU 
D/VLC: [a2fb1bb8/af3] core generic: creating audio output
D/VLC: [9e542528/af3] core audio output: looking for audio output module matching "opensles": 4 candidates
W/libOpenSLES: class OutputMix interface 0 requested but unavailable MPH=43
D/VLC: [9e542528/af3] core audio output: using audio output module "opensles_android"
D/VLC: [a2fb1bb8/af3] core generic: keeping audio output
W/EGL-DRI2: Native format mismatch: 0x1 != 0x5
D/VideoActivity: onSurfacesCreated org.videolan.libvlc.AWindow@95d92e7
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/af3] core input: Creating an input for 'big_buck_bunny.mp4'
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: using default timeshift path
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4' gives access `http' demux `' path `clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
D/VLC: [af3f38e8/b5f] core input source: specified demux: any
D/VLC: [af3f38e8/b5f] core input source: creating demux: access='http' demux='any' location='clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4' file='(null)'
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] core demux: looking for access_demux module matching "http": 6 candidates
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] core demux: no access_demux modules matched
D/VLC: [af3f3a28/b5f] core stream: creating access: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4

************[I've cut this part for characters restriction reason. Please follow the link above for full log]**************

D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: Found video Rtp: m=video
W/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: elst box found
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux:    - [0] duration=60095ms media time=0ms) rate=1.0
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: track[Id 0x3] read 240 chunk
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
W/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: STTS table of 2 entries
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: track[Id 0x3] read 1440 samples length:60s
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] essetup demux: Unrecognized FourCC rtp 
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: adding track[Id 0x3] video (disable) language eng
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: Found audio Rtp: m=audio
W/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: elst box found
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux:    - [0] duration=60095ms media time=0ms) rate=1.0
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: track[Id 0x4] read 241 chunk
W/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: STTS table of 3 entries
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: track[Id 0x4] read 648 samples length:60s
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: adding track[Id 0x4] audio (disable) language eng
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] fragments demux: fragment offset 24, data 37130<->5510872 @0, durations (null)
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] core demux: using demux module "mp4"
D/VLC: [af3f3a28/b62] h1conn stream: outgoing request:
       GET /big_buck_bunny.mp4 HTTP/1.1
       Host: clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de
       Accept: */*
       Accept-Language: en_US
       User-Agent: VLC/3.0.0-git LibVLC/3.0.0-git
       If-Match: "5416d8-47f21fa7d3300"
       Range: bytes=5510872-
D/VLC: [a2fa42a8/b5f] core decoder: looking for decoder module matching "mediacodec_ndk,iomx,all": 40 candidates
D/VLC: [a2fa42a8/b5f] avcodec decoder: CPU flags: 0x0000003f
D/VLC: [a2fa42a8/b5f] avcodec decoder: codec (aac) started
D/VLC: [a2fa42a8/b5f] core decoder: using decoder module "avcodec"
D/VLC: [a2fa49a8/b5f] core decoder: looking for decoder module matching "mediacodec_ndk,iomx,all": 40 candidates
D/VLC: [a2fa49a8/b5f] avcodec decoder: CPU flags: 0x0000003f
D/VLC: [af3f3a28/b62] h1conn stream: incoming response:
       HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
       Date: Sat, 03 Sep 2016 20:40:58 GMT
       Content-Type: text/html
       Transfer-Encoding: chunked
       Connection: keep-alive
       Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d491331e46f4fe1fd02450fd87b2704231472935258; expires=Sun, 03-Sep-17 20:40:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.vorwaerts-gmbh.de; HttpOnly
       Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
       Expires: Sun, 03 Sep 2017 20:40:58 GMT
       CF-Cache-Status: HIT
       Content-Range: bytes */5510872
       Server: cloudflare-nginx
       CF-RAY: 2dcc0517a62d06d0-LHR
D/VLC: [af3f3b68/b62] prefetch stream: end of stream
D/VLC: [a2fa49a8/b5f] avcodec decoder: allowing 4 thread(s) for decoding
I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/VLC: [a2fa49a8/b5f] avcodec decoder: codec (h264) started
D/VLC: [a2fa49a8/b5f] avcodec decoder: using frame thread mode with 4 threads
D/VLC: [a2fa49a8/b5f] core decoder: using decoder module "avcodec"
D/VLC: [9cf662f8/b5f] core demux meta: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
D/VLC: [9cf662f8/b5f] lua demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/com.biti_kids.biti/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/reader
D/VLC: [9cf662f8/b5f] lua demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/com.biti_kids.biti-1/lib/arm/vlc/lua/meta/reader
D/VLC: [9cf662f8/b5f] lua demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/com.biti_kids.biti-1/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
D/VLC: [9cf662f8/b5f] core demux meta: no meta reader modules matched
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4' successfully opened
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: elst (0) gives 0ms (movie)-> 0ms (track)
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: elst (0) gives 0ms (movie)-> 0ms (track)
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: track[Id 0x2] using Sync Sample Box (stss)
D/VLC: [a2f24ea8/b5f] mp4 demux: stss gives 0 --> 0 (sample number)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2556x1438, max=2048x2048)
D/VLC: [af3f3a28/b6b] transport stream: connecting to clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de port 80 ...
D/VLC: [af3f3a28/b62] h1conn stream: outgoing request:
       GET /big_buck_bunny.mp4 HTTP/1.1
       Host: clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de
       User-Agent: VLC/3.0.0-git LibVLC/3.0.0-git
       Range: bytes=37130-
D/VLC: [af3f3a28/b62] h1conn stream: incoming response:
       HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
       Date: Sat, 03 Sep 2016 20:40:59 GMT
       Content-Type: video/mp4
       Content-Length: 5473742
       Connection: keep-alive
       CF-Cache-Status: HIT
       Content-Range: bytes 37130-5510871/5510872
       Server: cloudflare-nginx
       CF-RAY: 2dcc051a2b100cd7-LHR
D/VLC: [af3f3a28/b62] h1conn stream: connection failed
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 0%
D/VLC: [a2fb1bb8/b65] core generic: reusing audio output
E/VLC-std: aout_get_native_sample_rate: 48000
W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 1, track 22050 Hz, output 48000 Hz
D/VLC: [9e542528/b65] core audio output: output 's16l' 22050 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/4 bytes
D/VLC: [a2fb6ed8/b65] core volume: looking for audio volume module matching "any": 3 candidates
D/VLC: [a2fb6ed8/b65] core volume: using audio volume module "integer_mixer"
D/VLC: [9e542528/b65] core audio output: input 'f32l' 22050 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/8 bytes
D/VLC: [a2fa5ea8/b65] core audio filter: looking for audio filter module matching "scaletempo": 13 candidates
D/VLC: [a2fa5ea8/b65] scaletempo audio filter: format: 22050 rate, 2 nch, 4 bps, fl32
D/VLC: [a2fa5ea8/b65] scaletempo audio filter: params: 30 stride, 0.200 overlap, 14 search
D/VLC: [a2fa5ea8/b65] scaletempo audio filter: 1.000 scale, 661.000 stride_in, 661 stride_out, 529 standing, 132 overlap, 308 search, 1101 queue, fl32 mode
D/VLC: [a2fa5ea8/b65] core audio filter: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
D/VLC: [9e542528/b65] core audio output: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 22050 Hz->22050 Hz Stereo->Stereo
D/VLC: [9e542528/b65] core audio output: conversion pipeline complete
D/VLC: [9e542528/b65] core audio output: conversion: 'f32l'->'s16l' 22050 Hz->22050 Hz Stereo->Stereo
D/VLC: [a2fa6228/b65] core audio converter: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 7 candidates
D/VLC: [a2fa6228/b65] audio_format audio converter: f32l->s16l, bits per sample: 32->16
D/VLC: [a2fa6228/b65] core audio converter: using audio converter module "audio_format"
D/VLC: [9e542528/b65] core audio output: conversion pipeline complete
D/VLC: [a2fa65a8/b65] core audio resampler: looking for audio resampler module matching "any": 2 candidates
D/VLC: [a2fa65a8/b65] core audio resampler: using audio resampler module "ugly"
D/VLC: [a2fa49a8/b66] avcodec decoder: available software decoder output format 0 (yuv420p)
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 2%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 5%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 8%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 11%
D/VLC: [9d9e0728/b66] core spu text: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 1 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] core stream: creating access: file:///system/etc/system_fonts.xml
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] core stream:  (path: /system/etc/system_fonts.xml)
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] core stream: looking for access module matching "file": 23 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] core stream: using access module "filesystem"
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 12 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] cache_read stream: Using stream method for AStream*
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 13%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 16%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 19%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 22%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 25%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 27%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 30%
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] cache_read stream: starting pre-buffering
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] cache_read stream: received first data after 4 ms
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] cache_read stream: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 238 KiB/s
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
D/VLC: [9e4d3528/b66] core xml reader: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4d3528/b66] core xml reader: using xml reader module "xml"
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 33%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 36%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 38%
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: removing module "cache_read"
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] core stream: removing module "filesystem"
D/VLC: [9e4df1a8/b66] core stream: creating access: file:///system/etc/fallback_fonts.xml
D/VLC: [9e4df1a8/b66] core stream:  (path: /system/etc/fallback_fonts.xml)
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 41%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 44%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 47%
D/VLC: [9e4df1a8/b66] core stream: looking for access module matching "file": 23 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4df1a8/b66] core stream: using access module "filesystem"
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] core stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 12 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] cache_read stream: Using stream method for AStream*
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] cache_read stream: starting pre-buffering
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] cache_read stream: received first data after 0 ms
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] cache_read stream: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 3717 KiB/s
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] core stream: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
D/VLC: [9e4d3528/b66] core xml reader: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4d3528/b66] core xml reader: using xml reader module "xml"
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 50%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 52%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 55%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 58%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 61%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 63%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 66%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 69%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 72%
D/VLC: [9e4df248/b66] core stream: removing module "cache_read"
D/VLC: [9e4df1a8/b66] core stream: removing module "filesystem"
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: creating access: file:///vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream:  (path: /vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml)
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: looking for access module matching "file": 23 candidates
E/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] filesystem stream: cannot open file /vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml (No such file or directory)
E/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: File reading failed
E/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: VLC could not open the file "/vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml" (No such file or directory).
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 75%
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: no access modules matched
E/VLC: [9d9e0728/b66] core spu text: no suitable access module for `file:///vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml'
D/VLC: [9d9e0728/b66] core spu text: using text renderer module "freetype"
D/VLC: [9d9e1fa8/b66] core scale: looking for video filter module matching "any": 39 candidates
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 77%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 80%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 83%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 86%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 88%
D/VLC: [9d9e1fa8/b66] swscale scale: 32x32 (32x32) chroma: YUVA -> 16x16 (16x16) chroma: RGBA with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
D/VLC: [9d9e1fa8/b66] core scale: using video filter module "swscale"
D/VLC: [9d9e2328/b66] core scale: looking for video filter module matching "any": 39 candidates
D/VLC: [9d9e2328/b66] yuvp scale: YUVP to YUVA converter
D/VLC: [9d9e2328/b66] core scale: using video filter module "yuvp"
D/VLC: [a0758928/b66] core video output: Deinterlacing available
D/VLC: [a0758928/b66] core video output: deinterlace 0, mode blend, is_needed 0
D/VLC: [a081f2b8/b66] core window: looking for vout window module matching "any": 1 candidates
D/VLC: [a081f2b8/b66] core window: no vout window modules matched
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 91%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 94%
D/VLC: [a0758928/b6e] core video output: Opening vout display wrapper
D/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] core vout display: looking for vout display module matching "any": 4 candidates
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 97%
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Buffering 100%
W/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] android_window vout display: Could not initialize NativeWindow Priv API.
D/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] android_window vout display: using ANW
E/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] android_window vout display: can't get Subtitles Surface
D/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] core vout display: VoutDisplayEvent 'fullscreen' 1
D/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] core vout display: using vout display module "android_window"
D/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] core vout display: A filter to adapt decoder I420 to display RV32 is needed
D/VLC: [9d015728/b6e] core filter: looking for video filter module matching "any": 39 candidates
D/VLC: [9d015728/b6e] yuv_rgb_neon filter: I420(640x360) to RV32(640x360)
D/VLC: [9d015728/b6e] core filter: using video filter module "yuv_rgb_neon"
D/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] core vout display: Filter 'yuv_rgb_neon' (0x9d015728) appended to chain
D/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] android_window vout display: PoolAlloc: request 3 frames
D/VLC: [b4ce7268/b6e] android_window vout display: PoolAlloc: got 1 frames
W/VLC: [a0758928/b6e] core video output: Not enough display buffers in the pool, requested 3 got 1
D/VLC: [a0758928/b6e] core video output: original format sz 640x386, of (0,0), vsz 640x360, 4cc I420, sar 1:1, msk r0x0 g0x0 b0x0
D/VLC: [9d9e0728/b66] core spu text: removing module "freetype"
D/VLC: [9d9e0728/b66] core spu text: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 1 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: creating access: file:///system/etc/system_fonts.xml
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream:  (path: /system/etc/system_fonts.xml)
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: looking for access module matching "file": 23 candidates
D/VLC: [9e4df2e8/b66] core stream: using access module "filesystem"
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Stream buffering done (1540 ms in 305 ms)
D/VLC: [9d9e0728/b66] core spu text: using text renderer module "freetype"
D/VLC: [a2fa49a8/b6a] core decoder: Received first picture
D/VLC: [a2f9f718/b5f] core input: Decoder wait done in 582 ms
W/VLC: [9e542528/b65] core audio output: playback too early (-72928): down-sampling
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I changed for exoplayer and I'm impressed with the results. Don't spend time with VLCLIB.

Comment: thank you 'while true' i used exoPlayer instead of VLCPlayer and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

The sad fact is [libvlc sample](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample/overview) is pretty outdated.
As the poster commented, maybe avoiding VLC is an option.

For good or ill, libvlc worked on my old Android Tab(nexus 7) though.

As to the samples on the net, libvlc compiled with older versions of NDKs seems to contain TEXTRELs and good many of samples on github are affected by that.

I used self compiled libvlc-3.0.0-2.1.1.aar and made the following tweaks.

Removed interface:

```
LibVLC.HardwareAccelerationError //is now gone(idk what replaces this!).
```

Changed implementation of:

```
IVLCVout.callback.onNewLayout
```

To

```
IVLCVout.OnNewVideoLayoutListener.onNewVideoLayout
```

Instanciating LibVLC

```
mLibVLC = new LibVLC();
mLibVLC = new LibVLC(options);
```

To

```
mLibVLC = new LibVLC(getApplicationContext());
mLibVLC = new LibVLC(getApplicationContext(),options);
```

#### MainActivity may be broken

It's supposed to show us a list of videos that can be played but I could only see a button that plays only audio, so if you want to test VLC video feature, maybe you need to add some code for starting VideoActivity and call it.

```
    public void startVideoIntent(String path){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(VideoActivity.LOCATION, (String) path);
        mPlayingVideo = true;
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```